# Ordinal regression or multiple regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, modeling, ordinal-data, medicine

I'm using STATA and [this](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/whatstat/) page to find a proper test, but I'm not sure which is better fitting, an ordered logistic regression or multiple regression?

My dependent variable is life quality (ordinal from bad to good) and my independent variables vary in type such as age, pain, depression etc.

What would be the best way?

Comment: A point of clarification: "multiple regression" appears to mean regression with more than one independent variables/predictors. All your standard regression models, including ordinal logistic regression, can accommodate multiple predictors/independent variables. Multiple regression is not mutually exclusive with ordinal logistic regression. In some fields, I bet most people don't even say multiple regression, as it is a given. As kjetil explained, the type of independent variable is also irrelevant (i.e. in regression, it doesn't matter if they're continuous, binary, or categorical).

Comment: Well, it does matter in that you have to use dummy variables to handle binary or categorical covariates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, since the response variable you are modeling is not numeric but an ordered categorical variable, ordinary multiple regression cannot be used, so this seems a case of ordered regression, like ordered logistic regression.

The variable types of the explanatory variables do not matter, all types can be used as explanatory in all kinds of regression models. If you want some more specific advice we need much more context!

Comment: "The variable types of the explanatory variables do not matter, all types can be used as explanatory in all kinds of regression models"

This seems in contrast to the link I posted, where they specify both the nature of the dependent and the independent variables?

Comment: Well, it might look like a contradiction, but it is really not. They just organized the page that way. Categorical explanatory variables will be represented by dummys in all kinds of reg models, numerical variables directly (or in some basis expansion, polynomial, splines) in all kind of regression models and so on. A lot of what they list can be seen as special cases of some regression model.  Please post more details of your problem, like sample size, some plots, maybe even (a link to) the data.

Comment: Thank you Kjetil, when you say categorical variables are converted to dummy variables, do you just mean that hair color blue, brown, gray are converted to 0, 1, 2?

Comment: See  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28169/what-are-the-different-types-of-codings-available-for-categorical-variables-in